# CentOS の yum リポジトリで公式とサードパーティーの見分け方は？

Tags: centos, yum

下記で、CentOSのサードパーティーではないリポジトリはどれですか？

質問するまでの認識は、CentOSのリポジトリはすべて公式で、yumでインストールしたものはすべてyumで解決できるものと思っていました。
Fedoraとは異なり枯れたOSなので、取得可能なリポジトリもすべてそうなのかな、と思っていました。

```
$ yum repolist all
  読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
  Determining fastest mirrors
   * base: ftp.riken.jp
   * epel: ftp.riken.jp
   * extras: ftp.riken.jp
   * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
   * remi-safe: ftp.riken.jp
   * updates: ftp.riken.jp
  google-chrome                                                                                  3/3
  ius                                                                                        185/185
  リポジトリー ID                                   リポジトリー名                                                                                 状態
  C7.0.1406-base/x86_64                             CentOS-7.0.1406 - Base                                                                         無効
  C7.0.1406-centosplus/x86_64                       CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus                                                                   無効
  C7.0.1406-extras/x86_64                           CentOS-7.0.1406 - Extras                                                                       無効
  C7.0.1406-fasttrack/x86_64                        CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus                                                                   無効
  C7.0.1406-updates/x86_64                          CentOS-7.0.1406 - Updates                                                                      無効
  C7.1.1503-base/x86_64                             CentOS-7.1.1503 - Base                                                                         無効
  C7.1.1503-centosplus/x86_64                       CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus                                                                   無効
  C7.1.1503-extras/x86_64                           CentOS-7.1.1503 - Extras                                                                       無効
  C7.1.1503-fasttrack/x86_64                        CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus                                                                   無効
  C7.1.1503-updates/x86_64                          CentOS-7.1.1503 - Updates                                                                      無効
  base/7/x86_64                                     CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                有効: 10,072
  base-debuginfo/x86_64                             CentOS-7 - Debuginfo                                                                           無効
  base-source/7                                     CentOS-7 - Base Sources                                                                        無効
  c7-media                                          CentOS-7 - Media                                                                               無効
  centosplus/7/x86_64                               CentOS-7 - Plus                                                                                無効
  centosplus-source/7                               CentOS-7 - Plus Sources                                                                        無効
  cr/7/x86_64                                       CentOS-7 - cr                                                                                  無効
  epel/x86_64                                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                 有効: 13,744
  epel-debuginfo/x86_64                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                                         無効
  epel-source/x86_64                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                                        無効
  epel-testing/x86_64                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64                                       無効
  epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug                               無効
  epel-testing-source/x86_64                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Source                              無効
  extras/7/x86_64                                   CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                              有効:    515
  extras-source/7                                   CentOS-7 - Extras Sources                                                                      無効
  fasttrack/7/x86_64                                CentOS-7 - fasttrack                                                                           無効
  google-chrome                                     google-chrome                                                                                  有効:      3
  ius/x86_64                                        IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                         有効:    185
  ius-archive/x86_64                                IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Archive                               無効
  ius-archive-debuginfo/x86_64                      IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Archive Debug                         無効
  ius-archive-source                                IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Archive Source                        無効
  ius-debuginfo/x86_64                              IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                                 無効
  ius-dev/x86_64                                    IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Dev                                   無効
  ius-dev-debuginfo/x86_64                          IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Dev Debug Info                        無効
  ius-dev-source                                    IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Dev Source                            無効
  ius-source                                        IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                                無効
  ius-testing/x86_64                                IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Testing                               無効
  ius-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                      IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Testing Debug                         無効
  ius-testing-source                                IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Testing Source                        無効
  mysql-cluster-7.5-community/x86_64                MySQL Cluster 7.5 Community                                                                    無効
  mysql-cluster-7.5-community-source                MySQL Cluster 7.5 Community - Source                                                           無効
  mysql-cluster-7.6-community/x86_64                MySQL Cluster 7.6 Community                                                                    無効
  mysql-cluster-7.6-community-source                MySQL Cluster 7.6 Community - Source                                                           無効
  mysql-connectors-community/x86_64                 MySQL Connectors Community                                                                     有効:    213
  mysql-connectors-community-source                 MySQL Connectors Community - Source                                                            無効
  mysql-tools-community/x86_64                      MySQL Tools Community                                                                          有効:     96
  mysql-tools-community-source                      MySQL Tools Community - Source                                                                 無効
  mysql-tools-preview/x86_64                        MySQL Tools Preview                                                                            無効
  mysql-tools-preview-source                        MySQL Tools Preview - Source                                                                   無効
  mysql55-community/x86_64                          MySQL 5.5 Community Server                                                                     無効
  mysql55-community-source                          MySQL 5.5 Community Server - Source                                                            無効
  mysql56-community/x86_64                          MySQL 5.6 Community Server                                                                     無効
  mysql56-community-source                          MySQL 5.6 Community Server - Source                                                            無効
  mysql57-community/x86_64                          MySQL 5.7 Community Server                                                                     有効:    642
  mysql57-community-source                          MySQL 5.7 Community Server - Source                                                            無効
  mysql80-community/x86_64                          MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                     無効
  mysql80-community-source                          MySQL 8.0 Community Server - Source                                                            無効
  nginx                                             nginx repo                                                                                     有効:    298
  nux-dextop/x86_64                                 Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use                                                            有効:  2,724
  nux-dextop-testing/x86_64                         Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use - testing                                                  無効
  !remi                                             Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                          無効
  remi-debuginfo/x86_64                             Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                              無効
  remi-modular                                      Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                      無効
  remi-modular-test                                 Remi's Modular testing repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                              無効
  remi-php54                                        Remi's PHP 5.4 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php55                                        Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php55-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php56                                        Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php56-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php70                                        Remi's PHP 7.0 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php70-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 7.0 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php70-test                                   Remi's PHP 7.0 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php70-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 7.0 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  remi-php71                                        Remi's PHP 7.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php71-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 7.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php71-test                                   Remi's PHP 7.1 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php71-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 7.1 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  !remi-php72                                       Remi's PHP 7.2 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php72-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 7.2 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php72-test                                   Remi's PHP 7.2 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php72-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 7.2 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  remi-php73                                        Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php73-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php73-test                                   Remi's PHP 7.3 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php73-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 7.3 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  !remi-php74                                       Remi's PHP 7.4 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php74-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 7.4 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php74-test                                   Remi's PHP 7.4 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php74-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 7.4 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  remi-php80                                        Remi's PHP 8.0 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php80-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 8.0 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php80-test                                   Remi's PHP 8.0 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php80-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 8.0 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  remi-php81                                        Remi's PHP 8.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php81-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 8.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php81-test                                   Remi's PHP 8.1 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php81-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 8.1 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  remi-php82                                        Remi's PHP 8.2 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                  無効
  remi-php82-debuginfo/x86_64                       Remi's PHP 8.2 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                      無効
  remi-php82-test                                   Remi's PHP 8.2 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                             無効
  remi-php82-test-debuginfo/x86_64                  Remi's PHP 8.2 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                 無効
  remi-safe                                         Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                     有効:  5,108
  remi-safe-debuginfo/x86_64                        Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                              無効
  remi-test                                         Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                     無効
  remi-test-debuginfo/x86_64                        Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - debuginfo                         無効
  updates/7/x86_64                                  CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                             有効:  4,691
  updates-source/7                                  CentOS-7 - Updates Sources                                                                     無効
  repolist: 38,291
```

Comment: なぜですか, の単語が多い割に 調査したことが記されていません。代表的な Linuxディストリのもう片方, Debian系での「LinuxMintリポジトリーを Ubuntuで使うようなもの」で伝わりますか？ … ムリなら少し長めになるかも？

Comment: 「LinuxMintリポジトリー」という言葉は、今初めて聞きました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リポジトリー名 (=説明) が "CentOS" で始まるものが OS オフィシャルのリポジトリで、それ以外はすべてサードパーティーのリポジトリです。